# Backup of local folder to multiple removable disks

Tags: debian, backup

I have a server running Debian 7.3, with two RAID1 disks as system/data disks. I also have a removable SATA bay, where I have a backup disk. I have a few different backup disks, so I can swap disk when the backup is complete, and store that disk at some other place. If my house burns down, then I still have a backup.

I want to backup a local folder `/data`, that contains subfolders for photos, music and movies.

What is a good way to backup this data. Using `rsync`, a simple script, or maybe a different solution?

Comment: Have you looked at [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/), [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/), and their competitors?

Comment: Yes, i have found rsnapshot. I was afraid of how it handle different disks. If a make a backup to disk 1, remove it, and next day make a backup to another disk (disk 2), will that copy only the difference from the day before, or will I still get a complete backup on disk 2?

Comment: Yes, under those circumstances, rsnapshot would make a full backup on disk 2.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` is a very straight forward way to recursively copy, it also attempts to minimise copies of unchanged files. It works just as well in local mode as it does across a network.

Example

```
rsync -av source_dir dest_dir
```